# Converting a private RSA txt file to DER

Tags: openssl, rsa

I am attempting to convert a private RSA key file to a DER certificate. I was given a private RSA key file with ".txt" extension. In addition I was also given a password for the RSA key fie. I've tried several commands with openSSL 0.98 but none of them seem to work:

My private key which begins with a and there are no encryption parameters below:

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<random characters..>
```

Attempt #1:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -in SOME_RSA_Private_Key.txt -passin "SOMEPASS" -outform DER -out "SOME_RSA_Private_Key.der"
Invalid password argument "SOMEPASS"
Error getting passwords
```

Attempt #2:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -in SOME_RSA_Private_Key.txt -passin pass:"SOMEPASS" -outform DER -out "SOME_RSA_Private_Key.der"
```

Output from Attempt #2 states:

```
unable to load Private Key
45746:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:153:
45746:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1331:
45746:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:387:Type=RSA
45746:error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/asn1/d2i_pr.c:99:
45746:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59.60.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_pkey.c:125:
```

I also tried to rename the "txt" extension to "pem" and ran the same commands but results are still the same.

Any idea on why I'm unable to read this file??

Comment: Likely the PEM file needs a little bit of cleaning up. I'd start be removing all spaces and newlines (other than in the two headers) and clean it up so that it looks like a typical PEM file with lines of uniform, reasonable length.

Comment: Also be sure the PEM encoded key has line breaks before 72 characters. Its an anachronism from a bygone era. Back in the late 1980s when the PEM RFC was written, it was a somewhat arbitrary limit to ensure interoperability. I believe OpenSSL still enforces it, while many other libraries just consume it how ever its presented.